# Close Review Queue Questions

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

What questions do I get presented with in the close review queue?
I've been going through the queue lately and it seems like to start with I see random questions, then after a while they are targeted to me (i.e. tags I frequent/are in my favourites).

Is there any reason for giving me a few randomly selected (?) ones to start with, before giving me ones within my frequent/favourite tags? (Or maybe this is confirmation bias with me noticing random questions at the start of my reviewing session).

Comment: Notice that you can filter the queue by tag (and/or close vote reason), which does help a lot. Still as seemingly endless as crossing the Sahara on foot, but at least you get to decide what kind of landscape you walk through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're random: The questions in the close vote queue are those which have been flagged to close or have a close vote. There is a way to filter by tag (see the "filter" option on the queue), but there is no inherent sorting AFAICT.

My guess is that you're seeing this because you're active in the most popular tag on SO ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23)).